# $.fancybox.delay is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i am using this [plugin](http://fancybox.net/) and now i tried add some delay time before close a div, but i get this error

```
$.fancybox.delay is not a function
```

for this code:

```
$("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
     $(this).html('Foi enviado um email').removeClass('messageboxerror1').addClass('messageboxok1').fadeTo(900, 1);
     $.fancybox.delay(800).close(); 
     });
```

what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$.fancybox.delay` is not a function. See the [Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api) for a list of valid methods.

Try using a `setTimeout`, e.g.:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}, 800);
```